# Prove that $S=1+2+3+...+n$ is not a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I need help: I don't know how to prove that $S=1+2+3+\cdots+n$ is not a prime number, for any $ n \ge 3 $.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us your effort.

Comment: $n(n+1)/2$ factors into $n/2$ and $(n+1)$, or into $n$ and $(n+1)/2$, most of the time.

Comment: @ABC: "[M]ost of the time"?

Comment: Always is also most of the time. Also, $1\cdot 2/2=1\cdot 1$ or $2\cdot3/2=1\cdot 3$ may not be interesting factorizations for some.

Comment: Pretty easy! You should have spend at least 5 minutes before asking to anyone *(never mind)*.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: Show that $$1+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2.$$ What can you say about this number when $n\ge 3$?

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds!

Comment: That happens to me all the time. :-/

Comment: Because you were wasting time, wasting the time of the OP.

Comment: What? I was only saying that the OP should show some effort.

Comment: As I said, wasting time.

Comment: @ABC: I must disagree. It is never a waste of time to encourage effort in a post, since posts that show none are rather often closed (and even when left open, reduce the quality of the site on average).

Comment: @ABC I remain of the opinion that (despite the fact the all of the answerers have given very good hints), that Ahaan's advice is the most useful the OP has received on this page (not least because it applies to more problems).

Comment: Just see for yourself. You always get answers regardless.

Comment: @ABC I see your point, but that shouldn't stop others from encouraging the right actions. Thanks for your support, Cameron and Matt!

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $$ S = \dfrac {n \cdot (n+1)}{2}. $$ This can be proven easily via the method of induction. When $ n \ge 3 $, what happens?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The sum is $n(n+1)/2$. And either n or n+1 is even.